I have problem installing and using Pyke Solver
I am trying to use the Pyke solver on pycharm.
I have tried to follow the instruction here.
https://pyke.sourceforge.net/about_pyke/installing_pyke.html
I am using python3, so I downloaded pyke3-1.1.1
Here is the error I am looking at.
`python setup.py install
 SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.
    
        See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
self.initialize_options()
 EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.
    
        See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!`
`self.initialize_options()
no previously-included directories found matching '.hg'
no previously-included directories found matching '*\\compiled_krb'
no previously-included directories found matching '*\*\\compiled_krb'
no previously-included directories found matching '*\*\*\\compiled_krb'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.pyhist' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '\*.orig' found anywhere in distribution
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
pyke.__pycache__.ask_wx.cpython-311: module references __file__
pyke.__pycache__.krb_traceback.cpython-311: module references __file__
pyke.__pycache__.target_pkg.cpython-311: module references __file__
pyke.krb_compiler.__pycache__.kfbparser.cpython-311: module references __file__
pyke.krb_compiler.__pycache__.krbparser.cpython-311: module references __file__`


`error: \[WinError 32\] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\matt\\miniconda3\\envs\\logic_tool_experiment\\lib\\site-packages\\pyke-1.1.1-py3.11.egg'`

The best solution for me would be to just be able to use pip install pyke
But it does not work.
